# Using D3.js with the module pattern

Tags: javascript, d3.js, module-pattern

When `d3` calls a callback function, `this` seems to be set to the window.

How can I therefore set module-level variables in, for example, a JSON response callback?

In the below example, `MODULE.Submodule.bar` is set but `MODULE.Submodule.foo` isn't.

```
var MODULE = MODULE || {};

MODULE.Submodule = (function(){
    var foo = [],
        bar = [];

    var init = function() {
        d3.json('path_to_file.json', set_globals);
    }

    var set_globals = function(error, json) {
        this.foo = ['a','b','c']; // 'this' doesn't point to MODULE.Submodule 
        bar.push('a');
        console.log('foo: ' + MODULE.Submodule.foo); // foo:
        console.log('bar: ' + MODULE.Submodule.bar); // bar: a
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        foo: foo,
        bar: bar
    }
}());

MODULE.Submodule.init();
```

I thought about revealing `set_globals` and then making the callback from `d3.json` into `this.set_globals` but that doesn't help matters.

I've also tried simply removing `this` from before `this.foo = ['a','b','c'];` but that's no better either.

Comment: Are you saying that something like the above doesn't work for you? Also, have you seen this [article on reusable charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, yes: `MODULE.Submodule.bar` is set, but `MODULE.Submodule.foo` isn't. I could start `set_globals` with `self = MODULE.Submodule` but that seems a bit clunky.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. That should work with just `foo = ...` though, no?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Removing the `this` before `this.foo = ['a','b','c'];` doesn't seem to help. The `console.log` output still looks like it does in the comment just after the `console.log` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. It manages to clean things up a bit too by using augmentation to dynamically create the parent `MODULE` if needed.

```js
var MODULE = (function (module) {
    var sub = module.Submodule = module.Submodule || {
        foo: [],
        bar: [],
        init: function () {
            d3.json('path_to_file.json', set_globals);
        }
    };

    function set_globals(err, json) {
        sub.foo = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        sub.bar.push('a');
    }

    return module;
}(MODULE || {}));
```

Then just call `MODULE.Submodule.init()` the same as you were doing before.

Comment: This looks sensible. Can anyone confirm that this is a good way to go about this?